# Check if dictionary lists contain value and return keys

Tags: python, dictionary, key-value

I have a dictionary with a set of key:value pairs where the values are a lists like so:

```
my_dict = {7: [6, 13], 6: [7, 8, 9, 11, 13, 14], 8: [6, 14], 9: [6], 11: [6], 13: [6, 7], 14: [6, 8]}
```

I want to check which of the lists contain the value '6' and return the keys which correspond to the matches. (i.e. 7, 8, 9, 11, 13 and 14)

I have tried the following code:

```
def find_key_for(input_dict, value):    
    for k, v in input_dict.items():
        if v == value:
            yield k
        else:
            return "None"

keys = list(find_key_for(my_dict, 6))
```

But it returns the following error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

How can I work around this issue to return all the keys whos lists contain this value? Thanks

Comment: Those are not lists, those are `numpy.ndarray` objects, as implied by the error message. Although, for either `list` or `numpy.ndarray` objects, you want to use `v in value:` regardless...

Answer (score 9):

You can use `dict.items()`:

```
my_dict = {7: [6, 13], 6: [7, 8, 9, 11, 13, 14], 8: [6, 14], 9: [6], 11: [6], 13: [6, 7], 14: [6, 8]}
new_dict = [a for a, b in my_dict.items() if 6 in b]
```

Output:

```
[7, 8, 9, 11, 13, 14]
```

Answer (score 2):

You are close!

`dict.items()` returns two things:

- Key
- Value

The value, in this instance, is a list. So essentially your implementation was doing this:

```
6 == [6, 14]
```

That is why you will be getting an empty list every single time. For short idiomatic code, go with the answer @Ajax1234 gave. However, if you want to guard against both lists and ints, do the following:

```
def find_key_for(input_dict, value):    
for k, v in input_dict.items():
    if value in v or value == v:
        yield k
```

I also want to note that you should not be using `return` in a generator. This return statement is redundant as `[]` would be the same thing

Answer (score 1):

In your original code, I think the `if` line should be :

```
    if value in v:
```

Plus I'm not sure a generator is particularly useful here, since the laziness it offers is immediately canceled by the call being put in a `list()` call. One could do :

```
def find_key_for(input_dict, value):    
    result = []
    for k, v in input_dict.items():
        if value in v:
            result.append(k)
    return result
```

...which would then be easy to turn to a list comprehension.